# How to refresh lightning web components data when apex updates data?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, wire

I am updating my lead data from a Queueable apex class, because I have to wait for an api response to come back with some data.

In the same time I am displaying the data that the apex class updates on a lightning web component on the Lead Page.

My problem is that when the Queueable class updates the database with the new lead data, the 'lwc' is not refreshing.

Apex class:
Call api get data then->

```
update lead;
```

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Cég Vizsgáló" icon-name="custom:custom13">
        <lightning-record-view-form
            object-api-name={objectApiName}
            record-id={recordId}
        >
        
        <div class="slds-var-p-horizontal_small">
            <lightning-output-field field-name={name}> </lightning-output-field>
            <lightning-output-field field-name={address}> </lightning-output-field>
        </div>
        
        </lightning-record-view-form>
      </lightning-card>
</template>
```

js

```js
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';

import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Lead.name__c';
import ADDRESS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Lead.address__c';
import ERROR_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Lead.error_field__c';

import templateData from './CheckVatNumberData.html';
import templateError from './CheckVatNumberError.html';
import { getFieldValue, getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

const FIELDS = [
    NAME_FIELD,
    ADDRESS_FIELD,
];

export default class CheckVatNumber extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;

    name = NAME_FIELD;
    address = ADDRESS_FIELD;
    errorData = ERROR_FIELD;

    render(){

        if(this.errorData == null || this.errorData == ''){
            return templateData;
        }else{
            return templateError;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read up about [empApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:empApi/documentation) but be aware that this doesn't scale well because it is a type of cometD client, and these are a limited resource on your org.

Comment: This didn't help. I need to 'refresh' the lwc when the data arrives in the queueable, or to sync the lds with the database. How would you go around that?

Comment: You listen for the Change Data Capture events and receive these in the LWC, which can then get the latest data. Please read the documentation I referred to, including what that further references.

Comment: You are right. The empApi solved the issue on getting the new value, my only problem now is that I don't really now how to load the initial value of the field so that I can change it later. Could you help me with that? @PhilW

Comment: You can load record data via the [`uiRecordApi`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-lightning-ui-api-record.html) and its `getRecord(s)` wire, if that's what you mean?

Comment: I am trying to explain it in the answer could you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

NOT THE FINAL CONSLUSION

So the partial conclusion is that we can solve the main issue with [empApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation).

My only problem now is that how would you give an initial value to the fields, that you can later change in the `messageCallback` function

My initial (on load) data for the fields comes from a wire function:

```js
const fields = [NAME_FIELD, ADDRESS_FIELD];

export default class PlCheckVatNumber extends LightningElement {
    
    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;
    
    channelName = '/data/LeadChangeEvent';

    @wire(getRecord, {recordId: '$recordId', fields})
    lead;

    get name(){
        if (this.lead){
            return getFieldValue(this.lead.data, NAME_FIELD);
        }
        return '';
    }

    get address() {
        if (this.lead){
            return getFieldValue(this.lead.data, ADDRESS_FIELD);
        }
        return '';
    }
...
}
```

My `messageCallback`

```js
const messageCallback = (response) => {
            console.log('New message received: ', response);
            console.log('Updated name data: ', response.data.payload.name__c);

            // Response contains the payload of the new message received
            this.name = response.data.payload.name__c;
            this.address = response.data.payload.address__c;
        };
```

My new html file:

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="EmpApi Example" icon-name="custom:custom14">
        <div class="slds-var-m-around_medium">
            <div class="slds-var-p-horizontal_small">
                <p class="slds-var-p-vertical_small">Name</p>{name}
                <p class="slds-var-p-vertical_small">Address</p>{address}
            </div>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: Change your code so it always uses the `name` and `address` properties of the LWC (no longer as getters, but as properties). Just change the `getRecord` wire to be a function and, when the data is received, do something like `this.name = getFieldValue(data, NAME_FIELD)` and remove your getters.

Comment: Yes it solved it. I don't know why I didn't think about that. This is my first lwc project and got confused a bit. but thanks for the answers.